# How can I achieve an array of recipients in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Title is pretty poor so apologies for that, wasn't sure how to word what I'm looking for.

I'm building a site in rails and I have a message model and a user model. A user creates a message and I want that user to be referenced somehow to a group of recipients(basically an array of user_id's). I understand that I'm not able to add and array into and sql field.

I'd imagine the best way would be some sort of join table. Although I've also thought about having a message has_many users and message having a string field which is sender or recipient then I could just make a call like `user.messages.where(:type => "recipient")`.

I feel like that approach is scrappy and someone on here could maybe point me in the direction of a better approach.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your schema should be thus, with a join table as you say, joining users (recipients) and messages.  I'm calling it "message_recipient" here.

```
class User
  has_many :messages
  has_many :message_recipients, :as => :recipient, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :received_messages, :through => :message_recipients

class Message
  #fields: user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :message_recipients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recipients, :through => :message_recipients, :class_name => "User", :from => :recipient

class MessageRecipient
  #fields: recipient_id, :message_id
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :recipient_id
```

This is all off the top of my head, i think the associations should be set up properly but you might need to tweak.

Now for a message you can call `@message.user` to get the owner of the message (a User object) and `@message.recipients` to get an collection of User objects that the message was sent to.

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hey @max thanks for the answer mate. Just wondering as I'm new to rails if you'd be able to explain this line to me: `has_many :recipients, :through => :message_recipients, :class_name => "User", :from => :recipient` as I haven't seen from used before? thanks for your help.

Comment: When you're doing a `through` association, you need to know which association to use in the join model to get to the model on the far side.  Usually rails can guess at this (eg if it's :user when the join has `belongs_to :user` and you do `has_many :users, :through => :foos) but if it's not "obvious" (which is the case when the association name isn't the same as the class name it points to) you need to tell it.  That's what :from does.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your help. It seems there is no :from method for has_many though according to this list of [possible options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options) Is it possible you meant :source?